# Flutter: How to customize with a curvy Drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image]

I'm trying to customize a drawer with a certain curved style, is this possible?

If so, is there an example?

Comment: check this: https://pub.dev/packages/wave_drawer . you might want to check option to customize as per your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter offers great flexibility in building user interfaces, you can combine various widgets to get your desired output.

I made a demo of what you are trying to achieve. I added the code and output(as an image)

```
class SO extends StatelessWidget {

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      // bottom padding 
      endDrawer: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80),
        child: ClipRRect(
          // give it your desired border radius
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(250),
          ),
          // wrap with a sizedbox for a custom width [for more flexibility]
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 200,
            child: Drawer(
              // your widgets goes here
              child: ...,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            child: FlatButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              // open the drawer
              onPressed: () {
                _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
              },
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Open Drawer'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I really didn't know that an endDrawer existed

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Happy Fluttering :)

Answer (score 0):

If you check the code of the Drawer you'll see it's only a `ConstraindedBox` with a `Material` (and Semantics), so maybe you can copy the same code and do some minor changes to the shape of the Material

```
class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Creates a material design drawer.
  ///
  /// Typically used in the [Scaffold.drawer] property.
  ///
  /// The [elevation] must be non-negative.
  const MyDrawer({
    Key key,
    this.elevation = 16.0,
    this.child,
    this.semanticLabel,
    this.isEndDrawer = false
  }) : assert(elevation != null && elevation >= 0.0),
        super(key: key);
 
  /// Added so the shape changes left or right depending the position of the drawer
  final bool isEndDrawer;

  /// The z-coordinate at which to place this drawer relative to its parent.
  ///
  /// This controls the size of the shadow below the drawer.
  ///
  /// Defaults to 16, the appropriate elevation for drawers. The value is
  /// always non-negative.
  final double elevation;

  /// The widget below this widget in the tree.
  ///
  /// Typically a [SliverList].
  ///
  /// {@macro flutter.widgets.child}
  final Widget child;

  /// The semantic label of the dialog used by accessibility frameworks to
  /// announce screen transitions when the drawer is opened and closed.
  ///
  /// If this label is not provided, it will default to
  /// [MaterialLocalizations.drawerLabel].
  ///
  /// See also:
  ///
  ///  * [SemanticsConfiguration.namesRoute], for a description of how this
  ///    value is used.
  final String semanticLabel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    assert(debugCheckHasMaterialLocalizations(context));
    String label = semanticLabel;
    switch (Theme.of(context).platform) {
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        label = semanticLabel;
        break;
      case TargetPlatform.android:
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        label = semanticLabel ?? MaterialLocalizations.of(context)?.drawerLabel;
    }
    return Semantics(
      scopesRoute: true,
      namesRoute: true,
      explicitChildNodes: true,
      label: label,
      child: Align(
        alignment: isEndDrawer ? Alignment.topRight : Alignment.topLeft,
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
          heightFactor: 0.95,
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(width: 304.0), //304 is the kWidth of the Drawer
            child: Material(
              elevation: elevation,
              child: child,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( //Add this ShapeBorder to the Material
                borderRadius: isEndDrawer ?
                  BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(220))
                  : BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(220)),
                side: BorderSide.none
              ),
            ),
          )
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And in the Scaffold use it like a regular Drawer

```
Scaffold(
  endDrawer: MyDrawer(
    isEndDrawer: true,
    child: ... your child widget
  ),
  drawer: MyDrawer(
    child: ... your child widget
  ),
)
```

If you compare the codes, I just added the `isEndDrawer`, an `Align`, `FractionallySizedBox` and a shape to the `Material`

[image]